# Understanding (automatic?) Deref/coercion when adding references and values of numbers

Tags: rust

How to make sense of the following piece of code? I'm new to Rust but have background on C/Haskell and a little bit C++. The only reference I can find is to [deref coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html).

```
fn main() {
    let xs: [u32; 4] = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    let mut i: u32 = 0;
    for x in xs.iter() {
        if i > *x {     // It looks x is an iterator. Understood.            
            i = i + x;  // no error. (coerced)
                        //Quote: "Rust will do this as many times
                        //       as possible until the types match."
            i = i + *x; // no error (explicit deref)
            i += x;     // error about u32/&u32 mismatch. Why the magic failed?
            i += *x;    // no error (explicit deref)
        }
    }
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no auto-deref or coercion here, `i + x` works simply because `u32` implements both `Add<u32>` and `Add<&u32>`. If you check [the docs for `u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html), you'll find the following four trait impls:

```
impl Add<u32> for u32
impl<'a> Add<u32> for &'a u32
impl<'a> Add<&'a u32> for u32
impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'a u32> for &'b u32
```

`u32` only implements `AddAssign<u32>` but not `AddAssign<&u32>` ([this is a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32094) and <del>[will be fixed in 1.18 or 1.19](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41336)</del> fixing it [causes regression](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41336#issuecomment-297227879) which means this impl probably needs to wait for Rust 2.0), so `i += x` is an error.

```
impl AddAssign<u32> for u32
//impl<'a> AddAssign<&'a u32> for u32 <-- is missing.
```

---

Why does auto-dereferencing not happen? — Auto-deref only happens when it is a receiver i.e. the "`self`" in a method call `foo.bar()`. `x` is not a "self" argument and `+` is not a method call. So there's no auto-deref here. See [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) for detail.

Comment: Thanks your your answer and the reference.

Comment: I thought that `a + b` was sugar for `a.add(b)` (with `add` coming from `std::ops::Add`). If that were the case, `a + b` *would* be a method call with `a` being self, and auto-dereferencing would apply to operators. I wonder if there is a drawback to this approach because of which Rust chooses not to define operators like that.

Comment: @user4815162342 there is auto-dereferencing, but it applies only to `a`

Comment: @torkleyy No auto-deref won't be done between operators, e.g. `&mut u32 += u32` doesn't work. Which is why there are four impls for Add instead of two.

Comment: Given that there is no implementation of `PartialOrd` between `u32` and `&u32`, Rust would report an error if you do `i > x`. The design is still inconsistent as you can do `i + x`.