# Why does &v[1] + &v[2] have the same result as v[1] + v[2] in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm learning about ownership and borrowing.

The difference between `borrow1` and `borrow2` is the usage of `&` while printing in `borrow2`:

```
fn borrow1(v: &Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{}", &v[10] + &v[12]);
}

fn borrow2(v: &Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{}", v[10] + v[12]);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    for i in 1..1000 {
        v.push(i);
    }

    borrow1(&v);
    println!("still own v {} , {}", v[0], v[1]);

    borrow2(&v);
    println!("still own v {} , {}", v[0], v[1]);
}
```

Why do they give the same output, even though `borrow1` doesn't have `&`?

Comment: "burrow" != "borrow"

Comment: hey Shepmaster, what you mean by "burrow" != "borrow".

Comment: [burrow](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burrow): *a hole or tunnel in the ground made by a rabbit, fox, or similar animal for habitation and refuge*. [borrow](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/borrow): *to take or obtain with the promise to return the same or an equivalent*.

Comment: Note that you can write this `let v: Vec<_> = (1..10).collect();` instead of the loop.

Comment: Boiethios - good to know!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index operator (`[]`) for a `Vec<T>` returns a `T`. In this case, that's an `i32`. Thus `v[0]` returns an `i32` and `&v[0]` returns an `&i32`:

```
let a: i32 = v[0];
let b: &i32 = &v[0];
```

`v[0]` only works because `i32` implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).

`i32` has implemented `Add` for both the (left-hand side, right-hand-side) pairs of [(`i32`, `i32`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Add%3Ci32%3E-1) and [(`&i32`, `&i32`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27a%20i32%3E-1). The two implementations add values in the same way, so you get the same result.

See also:

- [What is the return type of the indexing operation on a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161/155423)
- [Understanding (automatic?) Deref/coercion when adding references and values of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43360850/155423)